# Tool for escaping all quotes in a string/file

Tags: text-processing, quoting, sql

I have a weird problem that I don't have a good way around.

My company, because reasons, stores scripting code in a database table. Don't ask. Whenever I have to insert a new version of the code, I have to go through the file and manually backslash all the strings to be able to run it in my `insert` statement.

Is there a tool which will escape all of the strings in the file for me so that I can just copy and paste without having to do this manual work?

The file will likely contain single and double quotes as well as quotes within quotes, ie `"this is \"weird\""`.

Here's an example of the query I'm running:

```
delimiter $$
insert into table (code) values ("package a.b.c; 
class SomeClass {
    var thing = "so \"weird\" and thing's stuff"

}");
```

I don't need spaces escaped, nor semicolons, but anything that would break my quotes should be escaped. The contents of the `thing` variable would break my quoting in the example given above.

Comment: Please clarify what you need escaped. You said that spaces should not be escaped for example. OK, what else should be? Only quotes? How about semicolons? In the example you show, you want one set of double quotes escaped but not the other. How would that work?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: And desired output of that example is...?

Comment: So, should the `$$` become `\$\$`? Should `\"weird\"` become `\\\"weird\\\"`?

Comment: Normally, every database (driver, …) already provides boilerplate (prepared statements, escape functions, …) to handle arbitrary data properly. Why not just use those?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to escape every double quotation mark and backslash you could use

```
perl -wpe 's/([\\"])/\\$1/g'
```

You could also use this with xclip:

```
cat myfile | perl -wpe 's/([\\"])/\\$1/g' | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Comment: This adds escapes backslashes to single-quoted strings.

Answer (score 2):

POSIXly you can safely escape any string into one concatenated string for reinput to the shell like:

```
alias "string=$(cat file)"; alias string
```

`alias` will hard-quote its output and prepend *(at least)* `string=` to head of the string. `bash` *(in a break with the standard)* also adds the string `alias` to head of the output. Still, you can get an `eval`-friendly quoted version of any string like:

```
string=$(alias "string=$(cat file)"; alias string)
string=${string#*=}
```

Or, to get it into your clipboard:

```
<infile sh -c 'alias "c=$(cat)" c' | sed 1s/..// | xsel -bi
```

Comment: `bash` does not add `alias` when in POSIX mode (invoked as `sh` or POSIXLY_CORRECT in the environment or `--posix`, `-o posix`...)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - yeah, that's why I used `sh` at the bottom - it will work even when `sh` is `bash`.

Comment: See also: `a=$'\n' ksh -c 'alias foo="$a"; alias foo'`, or single quotes, the OP wanted the text escaped for a SQL interpreter, not a shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I thought it was for pasting into a command-line SQL query? But, yes, `ksh` derivatives do the ANSI quote strings.

Answer (score 0):

bash:

```
> printf %q "this is \"weird\""
this\ is\ \"weird\"

> printf -v var %q "this is \"weird\""
> echo $var
this\ is\ \"weird\"
```

Comment: Can I pipe stdin? ie `cat myfile | printf %q | xclip -selection clipboard`

Comment: I also don't need spaces escaped and other characters, I'm pasting this into a MySQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle, mysql and sqlite all have `quote` function. `var thing = quote("so \"weird\" and thing's stuff")` may work.

It seems code is transformed one way. It's very difficult to reverse if only single and double quotes are escaped by backslash because we wouldn't know which one to remove.
A better way that can perform bidirectional transformation of plain as well as binary in safe way is base64 encoding.

```
echo \'\"\' \"\'\" \\
'"' "'" \
echo \'\"\' \"\'\" \\ | base64
JyInICInIiBcCg==
echo JyInICInIiBcCg== | base64 -d
'"' "'" \
```

can be compressed to save space.

```
wc -c  /usr/bin/bashbug
6957
gzip < /usr/bin/bashbug | base64 |wc -c
4094
```